# Is the muslim veil sexist towards men?

Tags: hijab, surah

I have several times read in, probably, right wing, media that the motivation for the Muslim veil (and general requirement that women must not "show skin") is sexist towards men. IIRC, the reasoning usually goes something like this: there are suras, verses or sunnahs (or other sources of similar importance) that suggest that women need to cover up in general, and with a veil in particular, because otherwise men won't be able to control their lust.

Is this true? In what sources is this prescribed? Are there any "counter-claims"?

Comment: Are you asking **Is veil sexist to men?** Or **sources for "without veiled women, men would be unable control their lust"**

Comment: @AbduRahman I am asking about the motivation for wearing a veil, especially if the arguments in my condensed version is a reasonable summary.

Answer (score 1):

No, the veil/hijab is not sexist towards men. According to Quran 24:30

> ˹O Prophet!˺ Tell the believing men to lower their gaze and guard their chastity. That is purer for them. Surely Allah is All-Aware of what they do.

As you can see in the above ayah, it doesn't say that men must only do this when a woman isn't dressed according to Islamic standards. A man must always lower his gaze regardless of what a non-mahram woman is wearing.

**Purpose of Hijab**

There are multiple reasons and benefits as to why the hijab is mandated which can be summarized, in an oversimplified manner, as to increase and preserve modesty individually and among the society, and to please the creator.

You can read these links that go deeper into the purpose of hijab:

- [The Purpose of Hijab in Islam](https://hawramani.com/the-purpose-of-hijab-in-islam)
- [Hijab: Spotlighting Servitude to God](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/hijab-spotlighting-servitude-to-god)
- [Ḥayāʾ: More Than Just Modesty](https://yaqeeninstitute.ca/read/paper/haya-more-than-just-modesty)